# regexp для валидации текстового поля

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Нужен regexp для валидации данных в поле input. Требования:

1. не должны содержаться пробелы в начале и в конце слова (между словами могут)
2. длина текста не должна превышать 100 символов
3. должны использоваться только a-z и цифры
   Пока что получилось вот что:

```
/^[a-z0-9][a-z0-9\s]{0,98}[a-z0-9]$/i
```

но при этом я не могу ввести в input только один символ (

Answer (score 0):

1. `^(?=[a-z0-9])` – проверяем, что первый символ не содержит пробела
2. `[a-z0-9\s]{0,99}` – проверяем, что середина содержит символы из доступного набора
3. `[a-z0-9]$` – проверяем, что последний символ не содержит пробела. Этот же символ может быть и первым и единственным, так как предыдущей части может и не быть, учитывая что минимальное количество символов из того набора указано равным 0.

```
/^(?=[a-z0-9])[a-z0-9\s]{0,99}[a-z0-9]$/i
```

Обратите внимание, что `\s` соответствует одиночному символу пустого пространства, включая пробел, табуляция, прогон страницы и перевод строки, а не только пробелу.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте опциональную, необязательную подмаску:

```js
/^[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9\s]{0,98}[a-z0-9])?$/i
//        ^^^                        ^^
```

Подмаска `(?:...)?` находит последовательность определённых в ней шаблонов один или ноль раз.

**Подробности**

- `^` - начало строки.
- `[a-z0-9]` - цифра или буква из набора ASCII
- `(?:[a-z0-9\s]{0,98}[a-z0-9])?` - необязательная последовательность

  - `[a-z0-9\s]{0,98}` - от нуля до 98 пробельных или букво-цифровых символов
  - `[a-z0-9]` - цифра или буква из набора ASCII
- `$` - конец строки.

См. [пример работы регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/PCuC9I/1).